# How to add a custom axis line to a google chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google scatter chart that has some significant thresholds in it. How do I visualise them?

Do I push some extra ticks on chart axis? If so how do I add just one and how do I style it?

I am aiming for something like this.

[image: Chart]

I am using [React Google charts](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another column, or series, with the same value for all rows...

this can be added using a data view with calculated columns,

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [0,  165],
    [1,  175],
    [2,  185]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
      calc: function () {
        return 150;
      },
      label: 'min',
      type: 'number'
    },
    {
      calc: function () {
        return 175;
      },
      label: 'avg',
      type: 'number'
    },
    {
      calc: function () {
        return 200;
      },
      label: 'max',
      type: 'number'
    }
  ]);

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 125,
        max: 225
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

here's another example...

add additional columns to the data table,
use `getColumnRange` for find the `min` and `max` x-axis values

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [0,  165],
    [1,  175],
    [2,  185]
  ]);

  var xAxisRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  data.addColumn({label: 'min', type: 'number'});
  data.addColumn({label: 'avg', type: 'number'});
  data.addColumn({label: 'max', type: 'number'});
  data.addRows([
    [xAxisRange.min, null, 150, 175, 200],
    [xAxisRange.max, null, 150, 175, 200]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    series: {
      1: {
        color: 'cyan'
      },
      2: {
        color: 'cyan'
      },
      3: {
        color: 'cyan'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: It's a way... but I am looking for something a bit cleaner if only just for the fact that I am providing data sources to my charts so that people could simulate same results.

Comment: there aren't any [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for this, not sure how else you would accomplish -- just need to add another column to the data, either with a view or to the original data table -- only need two data points, you can use `null` to fill in the other columns...

Comment: It seems that there was but now it's deprecated:
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#axis-tick-mark-styles-chxtc

Comment: Oh... That actually makes much more sense now. I will give it a day if there are no global tick styling push commands or something I will count yours as the correct answer.
P.S. Thanks for the second sample.